# Using decorator pattern without adding "different" behaviour

Tags: java, design-patterns, decorator

I have facade interface where users can ask for information about lets say Engineers. That information should be transferred as JSON of which we made a DTO for. Now keep in mind that I have multiple datasources that can provide an item to this list of DTO.

So I believe right now that I can use Decorative Pattern by adding handler of the datasource to the `myEngineerListDTO` of type `List<EngineerDTO>`. So by that I mean all the datasources have the same DTO.

This picture below shows that VerticalScrollbar and HorizontalScrollBar have  different behaviours added. Which means they add behaviour to the WindowDecorator interface.
[image]

My question, does my situation fit the decorator pattern? Do I specifically need to add a behaviour to use this pattern? And is there another pattern that does fit my situation? I have already considered Chain of Responsibility pattern, but because I don't need to terminate my chain on any given moment, i thought maybe Decorator pattern would be better.

Edit: 
My end result should be: `List<EngineersDTO>` from all datasources. The reason I want to add this pattern is so that I can easily add another datasource behind the rest of the "pipeline". This datasource, just like the others, will have `addEngineersDTOToList` method.

Comment: In my opinion, your use case fits the decorator pattern (adding different behvaiour, in your case different scrollbars). Here is another example of how to use the decorator pattern: https://www.oodesign.com/decorator-pattern-gui-example-java-sourcecode.html, maybe it helps

Comment: @ItFreak I don't think their question is about GUI's. OP is trying to create a POJO from multiple sources.

Comment: So what you are trying to do? You're trying to implement an API which is a data aggregate for multiple other remote services? How does the user control  which combination of data to provide in the DTO, or are they fixed API's?

Comment: @flakes i was not sure, the UML showed a GUI implementation

Comment: @ItFreak That's what I thought on first read-through as well. The question should probably be refactored a bit.

Comment: @ItFreak It's not about scrollbars or GUI. This was just an example which displays adding behavior clearly.

Comment: @flakes Yes, the user can give a filter parameter. Like "City" or "lastname". Then my function should go through every datasource and find the data (if any at all). And yes idd it's from remote services'

Comment: @deltu100 If you know upfront which data belongs to which decorator, then the decorator pattern may be fine here. You wouldn't want to run a decorator if the  data provided by a specific decorator was not requested. A better solution may be a "Chain-of-responsibility pattern" which is similar to the decorator pattern, however, each link in the chain is allowed to either work on the item, ignore the item, or end the execution. This would be helpful for deciding if a call needs to be made, or terminating the chain if the work is complete for the request.

Comment: @flakes yea the first thing i considered for this was the chain of responsibility. Though I don't need the terminating the chain part. For that reason I thought decorator pattern might be better. The only way my series of datasources ignore is when they don't have the data, but I have no reason to terminate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*To further illustrate on how you can [Chain-of-responsibility pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain-of-responsibility_pattern) I put together a small example. I believe you should be able to adapt this solution to suit the needs of your real world problem.*

---

### Problem Space

We have an unknown set of user requests which contain the name of properties to be retrieved. There are multiple datasources which each have varying amounts of properties. We want to search through all possible data sources until all of the properties from the request have been discovered. Some data types and data sources might look like bellow *(note I am using [Lombok](https://projectlombok.org/) for brevity)*:

```java
@lombok.Data
class FooBarData {
    private final String foo;
    private final String bar;
}

@lombok.Data
class FizzBuzzData {
    private final String fizz;
    private final String buzz;
}

class FooBarService {
    public FooBarData invoke() {
        System.out.println("This is an expensive FooBar call");
        return new FooBarData("FOO", "BAR");
    }
}

class FizzBuzzService {
    public FizzBuzzData invoke() {
        System.out.println("This is an expensive FizzBuzz call");
        return new FizzBuzzData("FIZZ", "BUZZ");
    }
}
```

Our end user might require multiple ways to resolve the data. The following could be a valid user input and expected response:

```
// Input
"foobar", "foo", "fizz"

// Output
{
  "foobar" : {
    "foo" : "FOO",
    "bar" : "BAR"
  },
  "foo" : "FOO",
  "fizz" : "FIZZ"
}
```

A basic interface and simple concrete implementation for our property resolver might look like bellow:

```java
interface PropertyResolver {
    Map<String, Object> resolve(List<String> properties);
}

class UnknownResolver implements PropertyResolver {
    @Override
    public Map<String, Object> resolve(List<String> properties) {
        Map<String, Object> result = new HashMap<>();
        for (String property : properties) {
            result.put(property, "Unknown");
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

### Solution Space

Rather than using a normal *"Decorator pattern"*, a better solution may be a ***"Chain-of-responsibility pattern"***. This pattern is similar to the decorator pattern, however, each link in the chain is allowed to either work on the item, ignore the item, or end the execution. This is helpful for deciding if a call needs to be made, or terminating the chain if the work is complete for the request. Another difference from the decorator pattern is that `resolve` will not be overriden by each of the concrete classes; our abstract class can call out to the sub class when required using abstract methods.

*Back to the problem at hand...* For each resolver we need two components. A way to fetch data from our remote service, and a way to extract all the required properties from the data retrieved. For fetching the data we can provide an abstract method. For extracting a property from the fetched data we can make a small interface and maintain a list of these extractors seeing as multiple properties can be pulled from a single piece of data:

```java
interface PropertyExtractor<Data> {
    Object extract(Data data);
}

abstract class PropertyResolverChain<Data> implements PropertyResolver {
    private final Map<String, PropertyExtractor<Data>> extractors = new HashMap<>();
    private final PropertyResolver successor;

    protected PropertyResolverChain(PropertyResolver successor) {
        this.successor = successor;
    }

    protected abstract Data getData();

    protected final void setBinding(String property, PropertyExtractor<Data> extractor) {
        extractors.put(property, extractor);
    }

    @Override
    public Map<String, Object> resolve(List<String> properties) {
        ...
    }
}
```

The basic idea for the `resolve` method is to first evaluate which `properties` can be fulfilled by this `PropertyResolver` instance. If there are eligible properties then we will fetch the data using `getData`. For each eligible property we extract the property value and add it to a result map. Each property which cannot be resolved, the `successor` will be requested to be resolve that property. If all properties are resolved the chain of execution will end.

```java
@Override
public Map<String, Object> resolve(List<String> properties) {
    Map<String, Object> result = new HashMap<>();

    List<String> eligibleProperties = new ArrayList<>(properties);
    eligibleProperties.retainAll(extractors.keySet());

    if (!eligibleProperties.isEmpty()) {
        Data data = getData();
        for (String property : eligibleProperties) {
            result.put(property, extractors.get(property).extract(data));
        }
    }

    List<String> remainingProperties = new ArrayList<>(properties);
    remainingProperties.removeAll(eligibleProperties);

    if (!remainingProperties.isEmpty()) {
        result.putAll(successor.resolve(remainingProperties));
    }

    return result;
}
```

### Implementing Resolvers

When we go to implement a concrete class for `PropertyResolverChain` we will need to implement the `getData` method and also bind `PropertyExtractor` instances. These bindings can act as an adapter for the data returned by each service. This data can follow the same structure as the data returned by the service, or have a custom schema. Using the `FooBarService` from earlier as an example, our class could be implemented like bellow *(note that we can have many bindings which result in the same data being returned)*.

```java
class FooBarResolver extends PropertyResolverChain<FooBarData> {
    private final FooBarService remoteService;

    FooBarResolver(PropertyResolver successor, FooBarService remoteService) {
        super(successor);
        this.remoteService = remoteService;

        // return the whole object
        setBinding("foobar", data -> data);

        // accept different spellings
        setBinding("foo", data -> data.getFoo());
        setBinding("bar", data -> data.getBar());
        setBinding("FOO", data -> data.getFoo());
        setBinding("__bar", data -> data.getBar());

        // create new properties all together!!
        setBinding("barfoo", data -> data.getBar() + data.getFoo());
    }

    @Override
    protected FooBarData getData() {
        return remoteService.invoke();
    }
}
```

### Example Usage

Putting it all together, we can invoke the `Resolver` chain as shown bellow. We can observe that the expensive `getData` method call is only performed once per `Resolver` only if the property is bound to the resolver, and that the user gets only the exact fields which they require:

```java
PropertyResolver resolver =
    new FizzBuzzResolver(
        new FooBarResolver(
            new UnknownResolver(),
            new FooBarService()),
        new FizzBuzzService());

Map<String, Object> result = resolver.resolve(Arrays.asList(
    "foobar", "foo", "__bar", "barfoo", "invalid", "fizz"));

ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.enable(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT);
System.out.println(mapper
    .writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter()
    .writeValueAsString(result));
```

Output

```
This is an expensive FizzBuzz call
This is an expensive FooBar call

{
  "foobar" : {
    "foo" : "FOO",
    "bar" : "BAR"
  },
  "__bar" : "BAR",
  "barfoo" : "BARFOO",
  "foo" : "FOO",
  "invalid" : "Unknown",
  "fizz" : "FIZZ"
}
```